# Use online VM as default Gateway (Jump box)

Tags: networking, linux-networking, gateway

I have two Ubuntu servers:

- Server 1 (IP: 192.168.10.11)
  is online and connect to two network interface (internal, public)
- Server 2 (IP: 192.168.10.10)
  with no public access (internal)

I am trying to use server1 as a default gateway for server2, and this is what I've done:

```
# on online server (Jumpbox)
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.10 ! -d 192.168.30.1/24 -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# On offline server
route add default gw 192.168.10.11
```

Docker is installed on both (172.17.0.0)

They can PING each other, but from server2 it is not  possible to PING  Google.

Comment: try this on jumpbox: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o public_internet_interface -j MASQUERADE

Comment: @MartynasSaint I will get error when I add the interface name _No ... by that name_

Comment: Fixed above issue but still no ping from offline VM.

Comment: try to see if the rule is hit - iptables -vL . maybe docker puts some rules that are matched first

Comment: yes it is there, ip range for docker is in different range

Answer (score 0):

## Debian Style (the lazy way):

edit `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
iface eth0 inet static
address  10.0.0.1
netmask  255.0.0.0
post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/8' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/8' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

## The Lazy Crontab Way:

edit `/etc/crontab`

```
@reboot root "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/8' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/8' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE"
```

## Bash Style:

`nano /root/allow_lan_nat.sh`
You have to ajust the correct LAN that fits to you which might
192.168.0.0/24 (One Lan Subnet, Default Class C)
192.168.0.0/16 (all Subnets of 192.168)
172.16.0.0/16 (Default Class B)
10.0.0.0/8 (Default Class A)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#Ajust the LAN, as above shown
MYLANIP=10.0.0.0/8

#The IFACE that has Internet.
MYINETIFACE=eth0
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $MYLANIP -o $MYINETIFACE -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s $MYLANIP -o $MYINETIFACE -j MASQUERADE
```

run `bash /root/allow_lan_nat.sh`

## Direct answer to your question

Remind, that at i state this Answer, i dont know the Interface, so i assume ens3 s your interface that face to the internet, else update it like above

```sh
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward  
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.10.0/24' -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE  
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.10.0/24' -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
```

***REMIND, `ens3` must be the internet facing interface*** so update it to your needs.